# What is the purpose of the input output functions in Postgresql 9.2 user defined types?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I have been implementing user defined types in Postgresql 9.2 and got confused.
In the PostgreSQL 9.2 documentation, there is a [section (35.11) on user defined types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xtypes.html). In the third paragraph of that section, the documentation refers to input and output functions that are used to construct a type. I am confused about the purpose of these functions. Are they concerned with on-disk representation or only in-memory representation? In the section referred to above, after defining the input and output functions, it states that:

> If we want to do anything more with the type than **merely store it**,
>   we must provide additional functions to implement whatever operations
>   we'd like to have for the type.

Do the input and output functions deal with serialization?
As I understand it, the input function is the one which will be used to perform `INSERT INTO` and the output function to perform `SELECT` on the type so basically if we want to perform an `INSERT INTO` then we need a serialization function embedded or invoked in the input or output function. Can anyone help explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Types must have a text representation, so that values of this type can be expressed as literals in a SQL query, and returned as results in output columns.

For example, `'2013-20-01'` is a text representation of a date. It's possible to write `VALUES('2013-20-01'::date)` in a SQL statement, because the input function of the `date` type recognizes this string as a date and transforms it into an internal representation (for both using it in memory and storing to disk).

Conversely, when client code issues `SELECT date_field FROM table`, the values inside `date_field` are returned in their text representation, which is produced by the type's output function from the internal representation (unless the client requested a binary format for this column).